# Name separators, if condition for same command

Tags: macros, conditionals

I am new to LaTeX, just a Beginner, Basically a perl developer,

I have created a `.tex` file

```
\begin{document}

\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

\end{document}
```

Now my need is to define the commands, and the display should come as the below
>

1. `\iname` - Person Name will repeat several times
2. `\isurname` - Surname of a person
3. `\ifname` - First Name of a person
4. `\iname` will repeat any number of times, say 1 to ...

If only one `\iname` found inside `\cont,` display should be like the below

> Name1 K. C. G. Some title Text - 995.

If only two `\iname` found inside `\cont`, display should be like the below

> Name1 K. C. G. and Name11 Y. Q. Some title Text - 995.

If more than two `\iname` found inside \cont, display should be like the below (and should come after last `\iname`)

> Name1 K. C. G., Name11 Y. Q. and Name111 C.-Z. Some title Text - 995.

I am able to define `\iname` seperated by comma, but I don't know how to write a macro to define `\iname` with different outputs based on the if condition,

Is it possible to define that, I am totally a beginner with LaTeX, please guide me

Thanks & Regards